# How to pass an array as an argument for appSync query?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

hope you are doing great,

I created a query with an optional parameter, a list of ids, such list was described as an array and acted as a filter, which only retrieves the data that contains any of the ids included in the array.

Now if I call the query only with the required parameter it works fine, but when I include the array in the request it throws a type error. I am not sure how can I fix this situation.

*graphQL file:*

```
items(
    padId: ID!
    locationIds: [ID]
  ): [item] @http(url: "https://api-${env}/item")
```

*appSync request*

```
items(query: {
  padId: "63879aed-8f7a-4230-8215-921333ba198d", 
  locationIds: ["2b3a5532-73b1-4248-95d9-c91506d73493"]
})
```

*appSync answer*

```
{
  "data": {
    "items": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "items"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "MappingTemplate",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Value for field '$[params][query]' not a valid type."
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have found a solution but the documentation of appsync actually specify that both keys and values should be strings https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-http.html

My work around was to set the [String] to String and my FE is doing on Array.join(",") on the value for that field.

This is obviously subject to how your backend handle query arrays.